# asp.net list of users by profile property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-profiles

I have created some profile properties for when a new user is added to our system.

One property is called 'Client' and links this user to a particular client and stores a client id.

I am trying to create a page that shows a list of users for each client on the system such as:

```
Client 1
   User 1
   User 2
   User 3
Client 2
   User 4
   User 5
   User 6
Client 3
   User 7
   User 8
   User 9
```

Is there a way to get a list of users that match a particular profile property?

Thanks for any help. J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what i was looking for, ended up using this:
http://pretzelsteelersfan.blogspot.com/2007/03/get-aspnet-profile-properties-from-sql.html

Thanks for any help though.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is an old VB.Net method I wrote to filter users based on a profile value. It could be slightly modified to accomplish your task.

```
Function FindUsers(ByVal prop As String, ByVal val As String) As List(Of ProfileCommon)
    ' Use a generic list of people
    Dim peeps As New List(Of ProfileCommon)()

    ViewState("prop") = prop
    ViewState("val") = val

    ' Get all profile objects
    Dim profiles As ProfileInfoCollection = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All)

    ' Go through the profiles
    For Each info As ProfileInfo In profiles
        ' We need to turn a ProfileInfo into a ProfileCommon 
        ' to access the properties to do the search
        Dim userProfile As ProfileCommon = ProfileCommon.Create(info.UserName)


        If Roles.IsUserInRole(info.UserName, "Members Subscribers") Then
            ' If the birthday matches
            If val <> "" Then
                If prop <> "" AndAlso Left(userProfile.Item(prop), val.Length) = val Then
                    ' Add them to our list
                    peeps.Add(userProfile)
                End If
            Else
                peeps.Add(userProfile)
            End If
        End If

    Next

    If peeps.Count > 0 Then ShowUserDetails(peeps(0).UserName)

    Return peeps

End Function
```

Comment: thanks zackg, there is no built in solutions then. I'll have a play with this and let you know how i get on....thanks again.